# Fibonacci sequence but switching between adding and subtracting

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I've been experimenting with the Fibonacci sequence and had the idea to first add than subtract than add than subtract...

So if we start with $1, 1$ we get:

$1, 1, 2, -1, 1, ...$

This sequence is $12$ numbers long(it repeats after that).
And I wondered: Why is it $12$? That's my question.

I'm sorry that I ask such a stupid question but I just can't find the answer.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your question? It's $12$ because it just is. Do you want to know why it repeats at all? Or do you want to know why the period isn't longer or shorter? Can you give a more general property we can describe and discuss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the sequence is $a_n$ you're taking $a_{n} = a_{n-2} + (-1)^n a_{n-1}$.  If you start with arbitrary $a_0$ and $a_1$ you'll get $a_6 = -a_0$ and $a_7 = -a_1$, and then $a_{12} = - a_6 = a_0$ and $a_{13} = -a_7 = a_1$, and from there it repeats.

Another way of looking at it is with linear algebra.  If $X_n = \pmatrix{a_{n+1}\cr a_{n}}$, for the Fibonacci sequence you have $X_{n+1} = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 0} X_n$.  For your sequence you have $X_{n+1} = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr} X_n$ if $n$ is even and $\pmatrix{-1 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr} X_n$ if $n$ is odd.  Thus when $n$ is even 
$$X_{n+2} = \pmatrix{-1 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}\pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr} X_n = \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 1\cr} X_n$$
and $\pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 1}^6 = I$.

Comment: and when $n$ is odd $X_{n+2}=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{-1&1\\1&0}X_n=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&1}X_n$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&1}^6=I$

Answer (score 1):

You can express the relation between successive pairs of values as

$$\begin{cases}a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n,\\b_{n+1}=b_n-a_{n+1}=-a_n.\end{cases}$$

In matrix form,

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\b_{n}\end{pmatrix}.$$

The Eigenvalues of the matrix are $\dfrac{1\pm i\sqrt 3}2$ and they are sixth roots of unity, $e^{\pm i\pi/3}$. This explains why the sequence is periodic, with period $6$ (hence $12$ values in total).

The first powers of the matrix are

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ -1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix},$$ confirming the period $2\times3$.

In the plane $(a,b)$, the iterates form an hexagon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You defined $x_{2n}=x_{2n-2}-x_{2n-1}$ and $x_{2n-1}=x_{2n-2}+x_{2n-3}.$

Therefore $x_{2n}=x_{2n-2}-(x_{2n-2}+x_{2n-3})=-x_{2n-3}$

and $x_{2n-1}=(x_{2n-4}-x_{2n-3})+x_{2n-3}=x_{2n-4}$.

Therefore $x_{2n}= x_{2n-2}-x_{2n-4}$ and $x_{2n-1}=-x_{2n-5}+x_{2n-3};$

i.e., for all $m$, $x_m=x_{m-2}-x_{m-4}$.

This recurrence relation has characteristic root $\lambda$ where $\lambda^4-\lambda^2+1=0$.

Therefore $\lambda^{12}-1=(\lambda^4-\lambda^2+1)(\lambda^4+\lambda^2+1)(\lambda^4-1)=0.$

Therefore the sequence repeats after $12$ terms.

Comment: note:  I called the first element of the sequence $a_\color{red}1$